# Angular Material needs persistent scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-material

Using [Angular Material](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/), I am trying to get the dropdown menu to have a persistent scrollbar. Ideally the vertical scrollbar should appear when content is longer/larger than visual height of dropdown menu.

I have tried using `overflow` and `overflow-y` properties set to `scroll` on the `md-select` and `md-input-container` elements with no effect. not sure what to do but this is what I tried (and [here it is a plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/scv238pxEZqBHXs3mhas?p=preview)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Persistent Scrollbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">

    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdn.gitcdn.xyz/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.0.5/angular-material.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://material.angularjs.org/1.0.5/docs.css'>
    <script>
    angular
  .module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages', 'material.svgAssetsCache'])
  .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      state: 'CA'
    };

    $scope.states = ('AL AK AZ AR CA CO CT DE FL GA HI ID IL IN IA KS KY LA ME MD MA MI MN MS ' +
    'MO MT NE NV NH NJ NM NY NC ND OH OK OR PA RI SC SD TN TX UT VT VA WA WV WI ' +
    'WY').split(' ').map(function(state) {
        return {abbrev: state};
      })
  })

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>

  <div ng-controller="DemoCtrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" class="md-inline-form inputdemoBasicUsage" ng-app="MyApp">

  <md-content layout-padding="">
    <div>
      <form name="userForm">
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">

          <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm="">
            <label>State</label>
            <md-select ng-model="user.state">
              <md-option ng-repeat="state in states" value="{{state.abbrev}}">
                {{state.abbrev}}
              </md-option>
            </md-select>
          </md-input-container>

        </div>

      </form>
    </div>
  </md-content>

</div>

<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ngmaterial.assets.s3.amazonaws.com/svg-assets-cache.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.gitcdn.xyz/cdn/angular/bower-material/v1.0.5/angular-material.js'></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A working example (e.g. Plunker) would help you in getting an answer.

Comment: Here is a [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/scv238pxEZqBHXs3mhas?p=preview)